# Beautiful Soup Pagination, find_all not finding text within next_page class. Need also to extract data from URLS

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I've been working on this for a week and am determined to get this working! 
My ultimate goal is to write a webscraper where you can insert the county name and the scraper will produce a csv file of information from mugshots - Name, Location, Eye Color, Weight, Hair Color and Height (it's a genetics project I am working on).

The site organization is primary site page --> state page --> county page -- 120 mugshots with name and url --> url with data I am ultimately after and next links to another set of 120.

I thought the best way to do this would be to write a scraper that will grab the URLs and Names from the table of 120 mugshots and then use pagination to grab all the URLs and names from the rest of the county (in some cases there are 10's of thousands). I can get the first 120, but my pagination doesn't work.. so Im ending up with a csv of 120 names and urls.

[I closely followed this article which was very helpful](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-to-get-the-next-page-on-beautiful-soup-85b743750df4)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import pandas as pd

county_name = input('Please, enter a county name: /Arizona/Maricopa-County-AZ \n')
print(f'Searching {county_name}. Wait, please...')

base_url = 'https://www.mugshots.com'
search_url = f'https://mugshots.com/US-Counties/{county_name}/'
data = {'Name': [],'URL': []}


def export_table_and_print(data):
  table = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'URL'])
  table.index = table.index + 1
  table.to_csv('mugshots.csv', index=False) 
  print('Scraping done. Here are the results:')
  print(table)


def get_mugshot_attributes(mugshot):
  name = mugshot.find('div', attrs={'class', 'label'})
  url = mugshot.find('a', attrs={'class', 'image-preview'})
  name=name.text
  url=mugshot.get('href')
  url = base_url + url
  data['Name'].append(name)
  data['URL'].append(url)

def parse_page(next_url):
  page = requests.get(next_url)

  if page.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

  list_all_mugshot = bs.find_all('a', attrs={'class', 'image-preview'})

for mugshot in list_all_mugshot:
  get_mugshot_attributes(mugshot)

next_page_text = mugshot.find('a class' , attrs={'next page'})

if next_page_text == 'Next':
  next_page_text=mugshot.get_text()
  next_page_url=mugshot.get('href')
  next_page_url=base_url+next_page_url
  print(next_page_url)
  parse_page(next_page_url)
else:
 export_table_and_print(data)
 parse_page(search_url)
```

Any ideas on how to get the pagination to work and also how to eventually get the data from the list of URLs I scrape?

I appreciate your help! I've been working in python for a few months now, but the BS4 and Scrapy stuff is so confusing for some reason.

Thank you so much community!
Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to know the logic as to how you can get the content using populated urls derived from each of the page traversing next pages. This is how you can parse all the links from each page including next page and then use those links to get the content from their inner pages.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://mugshots.com/"
base = "https://mugshots.com"

def get_next_pages(link):
    print("**"*20,"current page:",link)
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("[itemprop='name'] > a[href^='/Current-Events/']"):
        yield from get_main_content(urljoin(base,item.get("href")))

    next_page = soup.select_one(".pagination > a:contains('Next')")
    if next_page:
        next_page = urljoin(url,next_page.get("href"))
        yield from get_next_pages(next_page)

def get_main_content(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one("h1#item-title > span[itemprop='name']").text
    yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for elem in get_next_pages(url):
        print(elem)
```

Comment: Hi SIM! Thank you again for your help. BS4 doesn't support "nth-of-type" selectors. So I'm having to work on this a bit. I see from the get_next_pages function where I went wrong for pagination.. but It's still giving errors about selectors. I'll update this if I figure it out, or get stuck... I really appreciate your assistance! I love love love this community and working with people from across the world on problems. If only our leaders could get on stack overflows level!

Comment: There is no way for the suggested code to break as I have tested it already. To get rid of the pseudo css selector errors, you need to upgrade your bs4 version. Thanks.

Comment: Check out ***[this link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*** as a proof of concept. Thanks.